# Not sure why my email script is not sending an email

Tags: python-2.7

It was working but after updating my Raspberry Pi, my python script to send an email is not sending and I'm not sure why. It seems to just hang without throwing any error messages and I have to Ctrl+C to stop it every time, otherwise it'll just sit there indefinitely.

Here is my code...

```
import smtplib, datetime

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

email_send = [sender email]
email_receive = [my email]
password = [password]
subject = 'Test Subject'
#sYMD = datetime.date.today().strftime('%y%m%d')
#lpath = 'C:/Path/to/files/'
files = ['log1.txt', 'log2.txt']

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_send
msg['To'] = email_receive
msg['Subject'] = subject
body = """\
Test Message."""

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

#filename = x.strftime("%y%m%d")+'_log.txt'

for file in files:
    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open(file, "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                    'attachment; filename="%s"' % file)
    msg.attach(part)

text = msg.as_string()

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_send, password)

server.sendmail(email_send, email_receive, text)
server.quit()
```

Here is what its doing when I run the script...

```
pi@raspberrypi: python send_email.py
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_email.py", line 36, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 265, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 317, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 361, in getreply
    line = self.file.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm sounds like the connection is timing out. Is it possible the client is unable to connect to the specified server and port? Try connecting directly with `nc` or `telnet` to confirm.

You can also pass a `timeout` value in seconds to the SMTP call:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587, timeout=5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried connecting with nc, netcat, and ssh and it just sits there, same as my send email script, until I send the terminate signal. However when I run nc -v smtp.office365.com 587 I get Connection to smtp.office365.com 587 port [tcp/submission] succeeded!

Comment: just to clarify, even though I get `Connection to smtp.office365.com 587 port [tcp/submission] succeeded!` running `nc -v smtp.office365.com 587` it still wont send an email